# How to read data in column-wise and put saved in mysqldb as a column

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

hi guys am trying to read data from text file which contains data column-wise like c1,c2,c3 etc I have to read these columns from text file and I have to save these columns in MySQL database as c1,c2,c3 columns but c1 column datatype int ,c1 column datatype date,c1 column datatype time.

```
class ReadFile 
{
    public String[] readLines(String filename) throws IOException 
    {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filename);

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line = null;

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            lines.add(line);
        }

        bufferedReader.close();

        return lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
    }   
}


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReadFile rf = new ReadFile();

        // The text file location of your choice
        String filename = "D://downloads//1_attlog.txt";

        try
        {
            String[] lines = rf.readLines(filename);

            for (String line : lines) 
            {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            // Print out the exception that occurred
            System.out.println("Unable to create "+filename+": "+e.getMessage());              
        }
    }
}
```

**Test JDBC**

```
public class TestJDBC {
    public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kallayyaDB";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "root";
        Class.forName(driver);
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        return conn;
      }


      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        try {
          conn = getConnection();
          String query = "insert into testTable(deptnum, deptname, deptloc) values(?, ?, ?)";

          pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query); // create a statement
          pstmt.setInt(1, 1); // set input parameter 1
          pstmt.setString(2, "deptname"); // set input parameter 2
          pstmt.setString(3, "deptLocation"); // set input parameter 3
          pstmt.executeUpdate(); // execute insert statement
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
          pstmt.close();
          conn.close();
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: You can then split the line into column data and use a `PreparedStatement` to insert rows into your MySQL table. What is stopping you from doing that?

Comment: I don't see any JDBC code here.  Have you tried something yet?

Answer (score 0):

In the loop part

```
for (String line : lines) 
{
   StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(line, "\t");
   String c[]=new String[3];
   int i=0;    
   while (st2.hasMoreElements()) 
   {
     c[i]=String.valueOf(st2.nextElement());
     i++;
   }
}
```

Now you can prepare your query using c[0],c[1],c[2], size is 3 as you have mentioned only 3 columns nd \t i have used assuming that each column have a gap of 1 tab. For date and time conversion from string  you can google.